# Creating multiple sublists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list `J` with `len(J)=2`. I want to create a sublist of each element in `J[i]` where `i=0,1`. I present the current and expected output.

```
J = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 7],[1,4]]
arJ1=[]

for i in range(0,len(J)):
    J1=[J[i]]
    arJ1.append(J1)
    J1=list(arJ1)
print("J1 =",J1)
```

The current output is

```
J1 = [[[1, 2, 4, 6, 7], [1, 4]]]
```

The expected output is

```
J1 = [[[1], [2], [4], [6], [7]], [[1], [4]]]
```

Comment: `[[[j] for j in i] for i in J]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this,

```
J = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 7],[1,4]]
new_l = []
for l in J:
    tmp = []
    for k in l:
        tmp.append([k])
    new_l.append(tmp)

print(new_l)
```

this will give you
`[[[1], [2], [4], [6], [7]], [[1], [4]]]`

Answer (score 1):

With simple list comprehension:

```
res = [[[i] for i in sub_l] for sub_l in J]
print(res)
```

---

```
[[[1], [2], [4], [6], [7]], [[1], [4]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in one line with list comprehension:

```
[[[k] for k in l] for l in J]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
J = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 7],[1,4]]
arJ1 = []

for in_list in J:
    new_list = []
    for x in in_list:
        new_list.append([x])
    arJ1.append(new_list)

print(arJ1)
```